# About the definition of independent random vectors

Tags: random-variables, definition, independence

I just have a question concerning the definition of independent random vectors.
The random vectors $X=[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ and $Y=[Y_1,\ldots, Y_m]$ are independent means that $X_1,...,X_n,Y_1,...,Y_m$ are independent random variables?

Answer (score 2):

No. For example $(X,X)$ and $(Y,Y)$ are independent if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. There is no need for the components inside each vector to be independent.